# Sending form contents as both html and ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an admin form that updates a model via a html submit. I'd like to be able to send the form's contents to an Ajax modal dialog for a 'preview' via a link or button in the admin form.

Is there a way to send the form's contents to the modal dialog via Ajax without breaking the html submit? So far all I can do is get the data into the modal as html which breaks the js rendering. All the Ajax submit examples I find attach to the form which will break the html submit.

Suggestions and/or pointers are appreciated.

We are using Rails 3.2.12 for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what it took to get this to work under Rails 3.2.12

View:

```
<%= link_to 'Preview Promotion UI', admin_preview_promotion_url, id: :promotion_preview %>
```

The above link is inside the form do/end.

Javascript in application.js

```
$("#promotion_preview").live('click', (function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
$.post("/store/admin/promotions/preview",
    $(event.currentTarget.parentElement).serialize().replace('=put&', '=post&'),
    {},
    "script"
);
}));
```

Rails.js injects some hidden code in the page that sets the type of response to PUT and then gets in the way of the routing. At least in this case simply replacing PUT with POST fixes things.

With this bit of code I can post my form updates as usual and activate a modal dialog "preview" using the form data.

Comment: The code is correct, my reasoning is wrong... if the form is #update the _method is PUT, if it's #create it's POST.

Comment: in jquery 1.9 `live` is removed user `on` instead

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it depends on how you are rendering your modal. If you're doing it server side and just need to get the form values to your ajax controller action you could do something like this with jquery"

```
$.post(ajaxUrl + "?" + $("#myform").serialize())
```

to generate a query string of your form values that you could sent to you ajax model.

Or if you're building the modal client side try

```
$("#myform").serializeArray()
```

to get an array of `name, value` pairs

Comment: why would you add query string in a post request?

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the direction I needed to go, see below for what I ended-up with to get this to work.